# Hurwitz's construction of simple covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, galois-theory

What is commonly meant by Hurwitz's construction of simple covers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most people understand under this term the following: It is a branched cover $X\to\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ of a compact connected Riemann surface $X$ to the Riemann sphere $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ such that the monodromy generators belonging to the branch points are transpositions. Or equivalently: If $n$ is the degree of the cover $f$, then each fiber $f^{-1}(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ has at least $n-1$ distinct points.

Comment: I don't mind getting a downvote - but still, a short explanation would be fine ...